# need to use one while loop o/p in 2nd while loop in same script

Tags: shell, unix

```
#! /bin/bash
set -x
while read x; 
do    
uid=$x    
mboxutil -lp user/$x/* | awk   '{print $7}' | sed '1,2d'  >> test1    
done; 

while read test1;
do    
echo "imcheck -m "$test1"|dedupbymsgid.pl > clean_dedup"    
echo "imscripter -u admin -f clean_dedup -v EBbo0C -s $1 -x zANv5*7UB#SFg$]#"    
done;
```

i need test 1 as an input for next while loop , where file1 is the name of file.

O/P for $TEST

===
user/d_raj/INBOX
user/d_raj/APS-COD
user/d_raj/APS.monitoring.CS
user/d_raj/Abundant
user/d_raj/Access
user/d_raj/Archive
user/d_raj/Cstation
user/d_raj/Cstation/C-station-commented
user/d_raj/Deleted
user/d_raj/Drafts

## user/d_raj/INFO:PROD::VIP

Answer (score 0, accepted):

instead of redirecting your o/p to a file you can save it in a variable

```
#! /bin/bash
set -x
while read x; 
do

uid=$x

mboxutil -lp user/$x/* | awk   '{print $7}' | sed '1,2d' >> test1

done; 

INPUT="./test1"

while IFS= read -r line
do

#echo "imcheck -m "$TEST"|dedupbymsgid.pl > clean_dedup"

#echo "imscripter -u admin -f clean_dedup -v EBbo0C -s $1 -x zANv5*7UB#SFg$]#"

echo "$line"

done < "$INPUT"
```

this will read line by line from file, assigning each line to $line variable once all line are read while will stop. INPUT is the path to file

Comment: Now if I take $TEST as an input in 2nd while loop it will consider $TEST as an string o/p , now say mat o/p of $TEST is.  as above edited .                                                                    Then is will be consider as one line where I want it as reading one lay one .

Comment: NOTE :The above o/p for $TEST is in coulum formate while uploading its takes in one line

Comment: I have updated my answer accordingly

Comment: "./test1.sh".   This was missing thanks a lot rampurwala